# Are There Any Plugins to HTML Encode Text in the VS Text Editor?

Tags: html, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, plugins

This may be a simple question since it seems such an obvious tool for any web dev..

I currently use a free web-based thing when I need to encode strings, but I was curious to know if anyone knows of a plugin for VS that will allow you to HTML encode text in the Text Editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a simple "plugin".

Goto "Tools" -> Macro Explorer -> Create new macro.

Sub EncodeHtml()
        DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text)
End Sub

Assign a hotkey. There you go.

Answer (score 0):

Plug-in, NO, but code? Why don't you just reference System.Web and...

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("input string");
```

You could easily build a console app which does that.

```
"".Replace("<","&lt;") // this is usually enough to escape HTML
```

...but maybe you want to encode everything so that your output is ASCII?

Comment: Of course I am aware of the code-based way of doing it, but I am looking for a way of quickly encoding text I paste into the editor. :)

Comment: I guess the easiest way then would be to just write that app and hot key it as an external app you could use it to grab, actually replace the clip board. That way you copy text (put in clipboard) hot key external tool and voila paste. That's three trivial steps an no hefty VS integration stuff.

Comment: Nice idea, wonder what it will be like to create a VS2010 plugin.. Apparantly it is much easier to create plugins in VS2010 for the text editor..

Comment: Yeah, I think it's gonna be awesome, and that's really important, the IDE usually doesn't provide you with everything you need, but if you build it with great extendability in mind, I think a lot of people will be a lot happier. Me included.

Comment: I'm totally physced about VS2010, there's like a million things I wanna do with the text editor.

Answer (score 0):

I only know this because I just found the answer and earlier while googling to find the answer I ran across this post.

If you're developing a console app in Visual Studio 2008 the System.Web Name Space isn't available. But, if you 'Add Reference' you can select the System.Web Name Space which will allow you to use the httputility and use the built in htmlencode and htmldecode.

Answer (score 0):

I move alex answer to Visual Studio 2013 with [VCMD extension](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/)

VCMD -> Commands -> Add and insert code:

```
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Class C
    Implements VisualCommanderExt.ICommand

    Sub Run(DTE As EnvDTE80.DTE2, package As Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package) Implements VisualCommanderExt.ICommand.Run
        DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Do not forget to add in References... -> System.Web